# Python and curve fitting

Tags: curve-fitting, data-fitting, model-fitting

I have a problem with curve fitting.

I have three points. Three different Luminosity at three different redshift, with errors.
I would to fit my points with a power law as: `A*(1+x)**B`.
I tried to fit this PL using `polyfit` (I transformed my equation in log-equation: `A + B*np.log10(1+x)` where A is my luminoisty in log10) but the errors is very big.

Also i tried to fit using `curve_fit` with a defined function as power law but also in this case the errors are big.

Lastly, I thought to fix B in the power law `A*(1+x)**B` to obtain only L value to contain the error, but I don't know how to do.

Any solutions?
`

Comment: Would you please post the raw data?

Comment: Yes!
`z1 = 5.7`, `z2 = 6.6`, `z3 = 7.0`. 
`L1 = 9.5*10**(42)`, `L2 = 10**(43.31)`, `L3 =0.92*10**(43)`.
`Max_L1 = 17.7*10**(42)`, `Max_L2 = 10**(43.72)`, `Max_L3 = 1.3*10**(43)`.
`Min_L1 = 6.4*10**(42)`, `Min_L2 = 10**(43.21)`, `Max_L3 = 0.77*10**(43)`.

z is redshift and L is luminosity. I wrote also the errors (UPPER and LOWER)

Comment: z1,  z2,  z3 are in order of increasing magnitude but L1, L2, L3 are not. Is this correct?

Comment: L1, L2 and L3 are respectively the luminosity at z1, z2 and z3